# PhpStorm: get code inspection warnings for "Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors"

Tags: php, constructor, phpstorm, code-inspection

Okay I've finally switched to PHP7. My code is a bit old and will be refurbished. Some of the problems are:

```
class MagicClass
    function MagicClass(){
        //etc
    }
```

Which gives an deprecation warning during execution:

> Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be
>   constructors in a future version of PHP; MagicClass has a deprecated
>   constructor in

This is good:

```
class MagicClass
    function __construct(){
        //etc
    }
```

---

How can I get PhpStorm code inspection to warn me for such errors in my current codebase?

Comment: which version of PHPStrom you are using?

Comment: Just use php linter `php -l` to list and fix it once and forever.

Comment: PHPStorm 10.0.3
php -l is nice, but howto setup for phpstorm?

Comment: *"Which gives me an error:"* What exactly gives you such "error" -- PhpStorm or PHP itself when executing?

Comment: fair changed the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not look like PhpStorm v10 supports this specific case. It has "PHP 7 Compatibility" inspection but it does not flag this code in any way (regardless what PHP Language Level you choose -- be it 5.6 or 7).

The solution is to install **"Php Inspection (EA Extended)" plugin** -- it has such inspection and it will work even if you choose 5.x as PHP Language level.

**Please note:** this plugin has a lot of inspections, some of which you may consider wrong/useless etc .. so you may have a need to go trough each additional inspection provided by this plugin and disable it if needed.

Answer (score 2):

In the `Preferences` (on OSX) or `Settings` (on Windows & Linux) dialog box choose `Languages & Frameworks` -> `PHP` on the left side list then check the `PHP language level` drop down box. If your `PhpStorm` is not very old then you should have PHP version 7 in that list.

`PhpStorm` uses the selected PHP version to check your code for syntax issues. It doesn't need to have the specified PHP version installed (I guess it comes with the interpreters.)

After you select the PHP version go to `Editor`->`Inspections` (also in the left side of the `Preferences`/`Settings` window) then in the right side make sure that the `PHP` -> `General` -> `Language Level` inspection is checked. In its description it says:

> Checks that language features used in the source code correspond the selected language level. (i.e. traits can be used only in PHP 5.4). Desired language level is set in the project configuration (Project Settings | PHP).

**Update**

Apparently, the current versions of `PhpStorm` doesn't handle this specific issue. I tested it with version 9.0.2, 10.0.3 and 11 EAP and none of them complains about PHP4-style constructors.

It seems the Language Level Inspection focuses on the usage of new PHP features more than on the deprecated ones.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not fix my issue. Yes I could run each file manually to check for errors or deprecation warnings. This would be a lot of work and there is still a chance of missing one. But what I'm trying to get working is comparable with typing mysql_query and this is then striked through. A comparable way to check for equally named functions as constructors. (btw yes i've configured php7+interpreter)

Comment: The interpreter is not used to check the syntax. Please make sure you have the code inspections enabled. I updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, this is all enabled, but there are still no deprecation warnings for equally named functions. Please try yourself with this code:
<? class MagicClass{
    function MagicClass(){
    }
}

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't issue any warning for this situation. I didn't notice it before because it's been more than 5 years since I converted or stopped using altogether code written for PHP 4.

Comment: Jup but PHP4+PHP5 compatible libraries are quite common :-)

Comment: And still no better solution in 2017.2

Answer (score 1):

[As of PhpStorm 2017.1](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/03/new-inspections-and-quick-fixes-in-phpstorm-2017-1/), there is a built-in inspection called "Old style constructor".

[image]

[image]