# mPDF error Message: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; m_pdf has a deprecated constructor

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

I want to print php to pdf using mPDF library in Codeigniter 3.x. But i got error message. The message is "**Message: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; m_pdf has a deprecated constructor**". How to fix it?
This is my mPDF file

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

class m_pdf {

```
function m_pdf()
{
    $CI = & get_instance();
    log_message('Debug', 'mPDF class is loaded.');
}

function load($param=NULL)
{
    include_once APPPATH.'/third_party/mpdf60/mpdf.php';

    if ($params == NULL)
    {
        $param = '"en-GB-x","A4","","",10,10,10,10,6,3';
    }

    return new mPDF($param);
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PhpStorm: get code inspection warnings for "Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35222415/phpstorm-get-code-inspection-warnings-for-methods-with-the-same-name-as-their)

Answer (score 3):

replace with this code

```
<?php
  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

include_once APPPATH.'/third_party/mpdf60/mpdf.php';

class M_pdf {

    public $param;
    public $pdf;
    public function __construct($param = "'c', 'A4-L'")
    {
        $this->param =$param;
        $this->pdf = new mPDF($this->param);
    }
}
?>
```

error occured because you use `mpdf` function inside `mpdf` class need to replace with `__construct`

> same class name function you can't use that is deprecated

You can use new `mpdf` library [enter link description here](https://github.com/phpclicks/mpdf)

Comment: Latest version (mPDF 5.7) still generates same error messages.

Comment: Did you check link that I shared

Comment: Yes i checked and write comment later.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
class m_pdf
{
 function m_pdf()
 {
   
 }
}
```

With

```
class m_pdf
{

 function __construct()
 {
   
 }
}
```

Or You can use higher version to solve this problem.